# Get class properties in t4 template (vs2015)

Tags: c#, .net, t4, system.type

using VS2015, I am modifying the default t4 template for controller&views scaffolding. In this template I have direct access to the properties of the related model, but I need to also get the properties of a class that resides in the same project as the templates. I have added this at the top of the t4 template:

```
<#@ Assembly Name="C:\_code\MyProject\obj\Debug\MyProject.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="MyProject.Models.Filtros" #>
```

and then I can get the properties of the class with

```
var listPropsFiltro = typeof(FiltroClientes).GetProperties().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

This is working ok.

now my problem is, instead of writing the name of the class in code (like here, FiltroClientes), I have to construct it for example with something like

```
var classname = "Filtro" + ControllerRootName;
```

and of course this is not working:

```
var listPropsFiltro = typeof(classname).GetProperties().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

I have found some posts about similar situations both here in stackexchange and other places, but none of the solution are working for me... 
so what should be the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for [Type.GetType(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) or [Assembly.GetType(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y0cd10tb.aspx)?

Comment: yeah typeof(classname) should be System.String ... not helpful.
if you're loading an assembly already why don't you load the project you are in, and then get types from that?
Granted you'll have to rebuild it to get uptodate results but shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`Type classType = Assembly.GetType(classname)`

and than call

`var listPropsFiltro = classType.GetProperties().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();`

You can try to get your current assembly with:

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`

If your executing Assembly does not equals the project Assembly containing your classes you could do something like this.

`Assembly project Assembly =  Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToProject)`

See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have tried it, but it shows error when scaffolding: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Assembly.GetType(string)'

Comment: The problem here is that this code is in a t4 template, and t4 templates are (as far as I know) always on their own (not related to any project or solution). so the getExecutingAssembly() method returns a temporary assembly. (ie. `string s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName` returns something like `TemporaryT4Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

Comment: still not working. it fails at the line `Type classType = projectassembly.GetType(classname);` with a `An expression block evaluated as Null System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ToStringHelper.ToStringWithCulture(Object objectToConvert)`

Comment: Are you using nameof(classname) or something similar?